# OnPostRender not working on grouped list view web part

Tags: list-view, client-side-rendering, grouping

Hi I have a view where I'm grouping the list based on two columns and I would like to add some CSS to the cells containing "Green", "Red" etc.

I have created a JS method `colorCoding` which takes care of coloring the cell containing the desired words.

I am calling the color coding method like this in my code

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
            console.log("calling color coding inside OnPreRender");
            colorCoding();
            console.log("color coding called inside OnPreRender");
        },// close OnPostRender
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            console.log("calling color coding inside OnPostRender");
            colorCoding();
            console.log("color coding called inside OnPostRender");
        }// close OnPostRender
      });// close RegisterTemplateOverrides

    }); // close executeFunc
```

It worked very well on the view when there was no grouping. But started to fail once I applied grouping to the list view. On sorting or filtering any of the columns the color coding is called as expected. **I need `OnPostRender` to be called on expanding a group.** It looks like `OnPostRender` is not called on expanding a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/122321/63689). It uses hooking into `ProcessImn` SharePoint function which supposedly gets called on expanding any group according to the answer.

I modified my code as below and it is now working

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
        callColorCodingOnGroupExpand();
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
            console.log("calling color coding inside OnPreRender");
            colorCoding();
            console.log("color coding called inside OnPreRender");
        },// close OnPreRender
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            console.log("calling color coding inside OnPostRender");
            colorCoding();
            console.log("color coding called inside OnPostRender");
        }// close OnPostRender
      });// close RegisterTemplateOverrides

    }); // close executeFunc


    function callColorCodingOnGroupExpand()
    {

        //Hook into SharePoint event to fix all links in group-by tables.
        var oldExpand = ProcessImn;

        ProcessImn = function(){
            var results = oldExpand.apply(this, arguments);

            colorCoding();

            return results;
        }
    }
```